# Line chart not rendering in Firefox or Safari

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, chart.js

I created an Angular 1.6 platform that uses [Chart JS 2.7.1](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.min.js).

The line charts render fine on Google Chrome 64.0, but not on Safari 10.1.2 or Firefox 58.0.2.

[ChartJS docs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/) show support for

> Chrome 50+
>
> Firefox 45+
>
> Internet Explorer 11
>
> Edge 14+
>
> Safari 9+

The only error I get is in Firefox: `ReferenceError: lso is not defined`, which has nothing to do with ChartJS:

[image]

Bar Charts and Pie Charts are loading fine in both Safari and Firefox; it's only Line Charts that seem to be problematic. The axes are rendered, but no lines appear (nor does the X axis):

[image]

In Chrome:

[image]

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24865501/chart-js-chart-not-displayed) says

> you have to put your script after the canvas declaration

My directive loads the chart onto a page, with its own template HTML. The template HTML *should* load before the javascript (I'm not sure that it is).

Would I have to force the directive to wait until after its template has loaded ([as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240639/how-can-i-run-a-directive-after-the-dom-has-finished-rendering))? I feel like Angular would complain already since it wouldn't be able to access the `<canvas>` element if the HTML wasn't loaded. I've tried this, and it doesn't fix the issue:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    run chart
    ... 
});
```

**lineChart.html:**

```
<div class="charts chart_{{chartId}}">
  <p class="subheading margin-bottom">stuff</p>
  <canvas id="line_chart_{{chartId}}"></canvas>
</div>
```

**lineChart.js:**

```
angular
    .module('LD')
    .directive('lineChart',['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                data: '=',
                chartId: '@',
                ...
            },
            templateUrl: '/html/directives/charts/lineChart.html',
            link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
                var lineChart;

                // Watch for date changes affect incoming datasets. Redraw charts as needed
                scope.$watch('data', function(n, o) {
                    if (!scope.data) {
                        return;
                    }
                    drawChart();
                });

                var drawChart = function() {
                    if (lineChart || typeof lineChart !== 'undefined') {
                        lineChart.destroy();
                    }

                    var ctx = document.getElementById(`line_chart_${scope.chartId}`).getContext('2d');
                    ...
```

What would cause this?

---

**EDIT:**

In Firefox, I am getting the following warning:

> Use of mozImageSmoothingEnabled is deprecated. Please use the
>   unprefixed imageSmoothingEnabled property instead.

When I `console.log(lineChart)`, I see this property:

[image]

where `lineChart` is:

```
lineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data : scope.data,
    options : getOptions()
});
```

Could this have something to do with it?

Comment: Any thoughts on this?

Comment: For me line chart is showing, but bar chart isn't