# Chart.js is not visible, but does show up on HTML

Tags: javascript, flask, chart.js, htmx

I am creating a dashboard, on this dashboard i make a call to some charts using htmx, but the chart is not rendering properly, when i inspect the element i can see the script, canvas and code but not the visual of the graph. I am using flask and python and this is my code pre the dashboard that calls the chart:

```
<div>
    <div class="toolbox">
        <h1>Budget</h1>
        <div>
            <div hx-get="/auth/budget/expense_form" hx-swap="innerHTML" hx-trigger="load once" id="expense_form_field">
            </div>
            <div hx-get="/auth/budget/dashboard" hx-swap="outerHTML" id="dashboard" hx-target="#dashboard"
                hx-trigger="load once">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> </div> </div>
```

And this is what html is returned:

```
<div>
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<script>
    const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

    const chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
            datasets: [{
                label: '# of Votes',
                data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                y: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }
        }
    });</script>
```

I have looked to the following similar questions, but i have not found any of their fixes useful: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24865501/chart-js-chart-not-displayed), [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44609165/charts-js-not-showing),[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29785623/referenceerror-chart-is-not-defined-chartjs)

When i check the console errors i am noticing this:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Chart is not defined
    at <anonymous>:4:19
    at At (htmx.org@1.9.10:1:22924)
    at Nt (htmx.org@1.9.10:1:23051)
    at htmx.org@1.9.10:1:10309
    at htmx.org@1.9.10:1:44741
    at oe (htmx.org@1.9.10:1:4604)
    at s (htmx.org@1.9.10:1:44716)
```

my thinking is that HTMX is affecting the script? Also when i inspect the chart element in browser it has an htmx class tag, could this be interfering with the script?

```
<script class="htmx-settling">
    const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

    const chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
            datasets: [{
                label: '# of Votes',
                data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                y: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }
        }
    });</script>
```

Comment: You can simply try to include chart.js globally in your base html template, instead of  inside the partial.

Comment: I moved the two scripts to base.html and then got: "Failed to create chart: can't acquire context from the given item"

Comment: Hi I solved it by moving the chart script back, thank you!